# Merges an array with a text file of integers and writes to the same file

Tags: arrays, c, text, merge, text-files

I want to merge a text file containing an integer in each line all the numbers in the file are sorted with an array of 10 sorted integers.

The output should be all the numbers from the text file and the array but sorted.

It works only for an array

> {11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99,100}

and a file containing

```
  10
  20
  30
  40
  50
  60
  70
  80
  90
  97
```

This is my function

```
void sort_tab_fiche(int t[10], FILE * fo){
   fo = fopen("output.txt","r+");
   int i,n,aux,k,tmp,num;
   for (i=0;i<10;i++){ //t[i]
      rewind(fo);
      num = line_number("input.txt");
      n=0; // n= which line
      do{ //aux = integer in the line
         fscanf(fo,"%d",&aux);
         n+=1;
         if(t[i]<aux){
            do {
               rewind(fo);
               for(k=0;k<n-1;k++){
                  fscanf(fo,"%d",&tmp);
               }
               fprintf(fo,"\n%d",t[i]);
               t[i]=aux;
               fscanf(fo,"%d",&aux);
               n+=1;
            }while((n)<=num);
            if((n)>num){
               fprintf(fo,"\n%d",t[i]);
            }
         }
      }while(n<num);
      if (t[i]>aux) {
         fprintf(fo,"\n%d",t[i]);
      }
   }
}
```

The for loop is to push the file pointer to specefic line

```
for(k=0;k<n-1;k++){
   fscanf(fo,"%d",&tmp);
}
```

**EDIT 1 (full code)**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int line_number(char * p) {
    FILE * f;
    int tmp, i = 0;
    f = fopen(p, "r");
    while (fscanf(f, "%d", & tmp) == 1) {
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}

//void sort_tab_fiche(int t[10], FILE * fo)

void main() {
    int tab[10]={11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99,100};
    int pos = 0;
    int i;
    FILE * in ;
   tri_tab_fiche(tab,in);
}
```

Comment: You have not described any problem nor asked a question. What issue do you have with the code? Also please provide complete code as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). That is, provide the test code and any other code needed such that any one can take it exactly as shown to run it and see your issue.

Comment: if i try with other numbers it just don't work i debugged but no conclusion.

Comment: You are still just giving us "doesn't work". Please be explicit. What exactly is the behaviour you are observing? Also, what debugging have you don? Have you stepped thru the code in a debugger to trace what it is doing?

Comment: it works only with the given exemple if i change the numbers in the file it wont merge the file with the array read the code asba